# Replace the Integer with a string in Ajax Jquery Laravel 4.2 BLADE

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

So i need to replace the **integer** of **the user's RIGHTS** that returns to my **view.blade** to a specific string for each number for example *1= student 2= teacher* etc. etc.

My ajax code:

```
$('#usersFind').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var val = $(this).val();

        var tbody = $('#usersResults');
        tbody.empty();

        if (val == '' || val.length < 1) return;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: base_url+"/getUsers",
            data: {data: val},
            success: function (data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                    var trow = "<tr>" +
                        "<td>"+result[i].lastname+"</td>" +
                        "<td>"+result[i].firstname+"</td>" +
                        "<td> </td>" +
                        "<td>"+result[i].id+"</td>" +
                        "<td>"+result[i].rights+"</td>" +
                        "<td class='text-center'><a href='something"/edit' class='enroll-btn btn btn-warning' ><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></td>" +

                        "</tr>";

                    tbody.append(trow);
```

My view blade :

```
<table class="datatable table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
                <th>lastname</th>
                <th>first</th>
                <th>something</th>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Rights</th>
            <th class="no-sort text-center"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="usersResults">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem your having? Did you try anything?

Comment: its not a problem i need to replace the  integer of  "+result[i].rights+"  with a specific word to my blade view ........cause now the it returns 1 2 3 etc etc  and i need istead of integers 1,2,3.... i need for  1 = student for 2 = teacher....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your API should be giving you back the appropriate **RIGHT** for each student. But for this answer I am assuming, you will always know all the **RIGHTS** and their mapping to the **INTEGERS** will never change.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_url+"/getUsers",
        data: {data: val},
        success: function (data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            var i;

            // Your Rights Map
            var rights = {1: 'Student', 2: 'Teacher' ...};                

            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                var trow = "<tr>" +
                    "<td>"+result[i].lastname+"</td>" +
                    "<td>"+result[i].firstname+"</td>" +
                    "<td> </td>" +
                    "<td>"+result[i].id+"</td>" +
                    // Get Rights from the Map
                    "<td>"+rights[result[i].rights]+"</td>" +
                    "<td class='text-center'><a href='something"/edit' class='enroll-btn btn btn-warning' ><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></td>" +

                    "</tr>";

                tbody.append(trow);
```

Comment: A lot of thanks you have really helped me ! Have a nice day !